# PHP WSDL SOAP Can't Import Schema

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I'm trying to use an external webservice but I get the error `Parsing Schema: can't import schema from webservice_url`. The service uses HTTP Basic authentication and is using SSL. I can login via a web browser and see the xml it produces but I can't change what is generated since it is not my code generating the xml. I have the following code.

```
$config = array('login' => $user_id, 'password' => $password);
$client = new SoapClient($url, $config);
```

Comment: Are you sure the URL is generating XML?

Comment: Can you post the XML that you see through the browser?  What is the value of $url?

Comment: Can you save the WSDL locally and point PHP to that, without the user/pass?

Comment: As in just save the xml file locally and output it from some script on my local server?

Comment: Yes, save it locally and then replace $url with the local file path.

Comment: It might be having trouble importing that schema definition.  Try to save that locally, too, and change the schemaLocation in the local WSDL file.

Comment: Hmm. I'll give it a shot. I wonder if the schema url asks for the login information as well and that's why it fails

Comment: Could very well be the same problem as this one: [401 Authentication Error when SoapClient tries to fetch schema file](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39912332/839332)

Comment: That's the issue @TommyBravo. It's silly having to save the schema. I ended up using Ruby since it doesn't require saving the schema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well after researching and reading a bunch of articles online it seems like this is a limitation of php-soap and some suggestions point at using curl to accomplish. I actually decided to avoid PHP entirely since I just learned Ruby and have been going away from PHP. I accomplished my above task by using the `Savon` gem which has some pretty good documentation on the authentication and setting the cookie. It works great using this gem.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the SoapClient manual page's [comment section](http://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapclient.php#88902):

```
<?php 

$login = 'someone';
$password = 'secret';

$client = new SoapClient(
    'https://' . urlencode($login) . ':' . urlencode($password) . '@www.server.com/path/to/wsdl',
    array(
        'login' => $login,
        'password' => $password
    )
);

?>
```

Seems like the basic authentication is for the endpoint invocation, not the WSDL retrieval.

Comment: Hmm. I tried that. Pointing it the WSDL gives the same error as in my question and pointing it to the schema gives `SOAP-ERROR: Parsing WSDL: Couldn't find <definitions>`

Comment: Oops!  had `http://` at the beginning instead of `https://`.  Edited answer to fix.  Did you change that when you tried?

Comment: Yes I did. I also put the port behind the address as well. I tried setting the `proxy_host` to the schema url but requests all come back `NULL`

Comment: Make sure OpenSSL support is enabled in your phpinfo()?

Comment: Says enabled and version is OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 2010

Comment: Thanks for the help I decided to go with the Ruby Gem `Savon`